# How to connect a bluetooth module? (How to get UUID of module?)

Tags: android

I want to connect a bluetooth module (LM400) with my android... `listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord` method needs the `UUID` of the module. Do you have any idea how can I get the `UUID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UUID is something you generate, not something you need from the module.

Comment: Yes, I can get the `BluetoothDevice`. And I want to set my android device as server and the other bluetooth module as client. So don't I need to have a UUID to send data? The main question is "How can I send data when I have the BluetoothDevice".

Comment: If you want to be a server, you want to listen with BluetoothServerSocket.accept().  The BluetoothSocket you get from that will let you determine what device is contacting you and you can decide to interact with it or not.  If you do, you can create input and outputstreams.

Comment: So how can I create the `BluetoothServerSocket`? I think I need a UUID to create a BB Socket.  mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(device.getName(), UUID);
Am I wrong?

Comment: I think I see the confusion.  I believe the UUID is something you generate, not something you need from the module.  I'll edit the original answer

Comment: Nice, you are probably right. And I need the last shot: how can I create the UUID? It gets two parameters, mostSigBits and least sigBits as `long`. But UUID generators generate alpha-numeric String.

Comment: UUID.fromString().  The BluetoothDevice doc suggests "If you are connecting to a Bluetooth serial board then try using the well-known SPP UUID 00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB."

Comment: Um, Android and bluetooth module has a paired connection. However `myServerSocket.accept()` is not returning socket. Any idea?

Comment: Not sure if this will help or not, you can also try generating your own UUID via `UUID.randomUUID()`.